# is it possible to have a <a> tag inside lightning-formatted-text?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I want to show the created name(which can click and link to the user record page) and created date.
This is how it look inside the formatted-text:
[image]

is it possible, and how to make the a tag avaliable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot have a formatted `<a>` element inside `lightning-formatted-text`. However, for your requirement, you can build your own custom HTML completely by using `<a>` & `<p>` (or `<span>`) tags and not `<lightning-formatted-text>`.

A better option would be to use `lightning-formatted-url` (*as shown in the sample code snippet below*).

```
<lightning-formatted-url 
    label="<Replace CreatedBy Name property here>" 
    value="/lightning/r/User/005XX00000XXxxXXAS/view" 
    tooltip="<Replace custom tooltip message here>" 
    target="_blank">
</lightning-formatted-url>
```

Comment: thank you, I realize that I dont need to output everything inside only 1 tag.